# Generic type for property of an Interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a set of data structures that looks like follows:

- different DataPoints that implement the `IDataPoint` interface (to secure the existence of a value and a coordinate point)
- each DataPoint might have different coordinate types (2D, 3D etc)
- the coordinates are stored in generic tuples that all implement the interface `ITuple` (to secure the existence of at least one (X) coordinate)

My problem is, that I haven't found out how to make the `Coord` property of the `IDataPoint` generic so that coordinates can be either 2d or 3d (or sth else if needed later on). This is my attempt:

```
public interface IDataPoint
{ 
    float Value { get; }
    <Tuple> Coords { get; } where <ITuple> : ITuple

    string ToString();
}
```

Where is my error or is this simply not possible?

Rest of the code

```
public interface ITuple<T>
{
    T X { get; }

    string ToString();
}

public struct TwoTuple<T> : ITuple<T>
{
    public T X { get; }
    public T Y { get; }
    public TwoTuple(T x, T y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(" + X + ", " + Y + ")";
    }
}

public struct ThreeTuple<T> : ITuple<T>
{
    public T X { get; }
    public T Y { get; }
    public T Z { get; }
    public ThreeTuple(T x, T y, T z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(" + X + ", " + Y + ", " + Z + ")";
    }
}

public interface IDataPoint
{ 
    float Value { get; }
    <Tuple> Coords { get; } where <ITuple> : ITuple

    string ToString();
}

public struct BarDataPoint : IDataPoint
{
    public TwoTuple<float> Coords { get; }
    public float Value { get; }
    public BarDataPoint(TwoTuple<float> Coords, float Value)
    {
        this.Coords = Coords;
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Coordinates: " + Coords + "; Value: " + Value;
    }
}

public struct ScatterDataPoint : IDataPoint
{
    public ThreeTuple<float> Coords { get; }
    public float Value { get; }
    public ScatterDataPoint(ThreeTuple<float> coords, float value)
    {
        this.Coords = coords;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Coordinates: " + Coords + "; Value: " + Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public interface IDataPoint<T> { ITuple<T> Coords { get; } }`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay it says that <T> is not in the namespace. If I add it via `IDataPoint<T>` it works, but then the implementation doesn't work again.
Because if I then say `BarDataPoint : IDataPoint<float>` it gives me an error because the return type for `BarDataPoint` is `TwoTuple` and not `ITuple`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface

```
public interface IDataPoint<TTuple>
{
    float Value { get; }
    TTuple Coords { get; }

    string ToString();
}
```

Usage

```
 public struct BarDataPoint : IDataPoint<ThreeTuple<float>>
{
    public float Value { get; }

    public ThreeTuple<float> Coords { get; set; }

    public BarDataPoint(ThreeTuple<float> Coords, float Value)
    {
        this.Coords = Coords;
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Coordinates: " + Coords + "; Value: " + Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot!
One question left is: how to I now use this in a function?
`public void ShowData<TDataPoint>(TDataPoint datapoint) where TDataPoint : IDataPoint<TwoTuple<float>>` works, but I would like to make the `TwoTuple` generic.

Comment: With this approach, you give up the constraint that the type of `Coords` has to implement the `ITuple` interface.

Comment: @tadeseus How about this? `public static void ShowData<T>(IDataPoint<T> dataPoint) where T: ITuple<float>
        {
            //loqic
        }`

Comment: Which means that 2D and 3D data points are now completely different types, that cannot be handled in a unified way.

Comment: @AdiletB that works again! You are my saviour. However, there is (of course) a last problem. The classes that use these data types dont work anymore..
`public class ScatterPlot : Plot<ScatterDataPoint>` doesnt work because " There is no boxing conversion from 'ScatterDataPoint' to 'IDataPoint'."

Comment: @AdiletB fixed it ;)
```public class ScatterPlot : Plot<ScatterDataPoint, ThreeTuple<float>>``` and for the base class ```public abstract class Plot<TDataPoint, TTuple> where TDataPoint : IDataPoint<TTuple>```

Comment: @tadeseus I'm glad you did it

Answer (score 0):

Do it like you did it in your `ITuple` interface by providing the generics and its constraints in the interface declaration:

```
public interface IDataPoint<T,T2> where T : ITuple<T2>
{ 
    float Value { get; }
    T Coords { get; } 

    string ToString();
}
```

Your `Coords` property now has the type `T`, and `T` has to implement the interface `ITuple<T2>`. Your class `BarDataPoint` should be defined like this:

```
public struct BarDataPoint : IDataPoint<TwoTuple<float>,float>
```

You'll have to tell the compiler the generic type of `ITuple<T>` twice. Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CYw1bR

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

```
public interface IDataPoint 
{
    float Value { get; }
    ITuple Coords { get; }

    string ToString();
}
```

you dont need generics. `ITuple` is general purpose base implementation for tuples.
these are all derived from `ITuple`

```
System.Tuple<T1>
System.Tuple<T1,T2>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>
System.Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRest>
System.ValueTuple
System.ValueTuple<T1>
System.ValueTuple<T1,T2>
System.ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3>
System.ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3,T4>
System.ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>
System.ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>
System.ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>
System.ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRest>
```

[ITuple Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: `ITuple` is generic.

Comment: It is an interface. not generic

Comment: `ITuple` as defined by the OP is generic.

Comment: my ITuple is not same as his ITuple. mine is Interface

Comment: OPs `ITuple` is also an interface. OPs `ITuple` also defines a property `X`, which I assume is required.